# How to customize XmlResponse in WCF service using WebHttpBinding

Tags: wcf

I need to intercept the response of a service created using WCF with `webHttpBinding` (REST based service).

Now I want the XML emitted in a customized way. For e.g, currently a service method returns output like this:

```
<User xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <UserCellInfo>+91-98102239</UserCellInfo>
   <UserDepartment>.NET Projects</UserDepartment>
   <UserID>A10129</UserID>
   <UserName>Jeff Thomson</UserName>
</User>
```

but I want it in a different custom way.Something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp>
   <User>
      <UserCellInfo>+91-98102239</UserCellInfo>
      <UserDepartment>.NET Projects</UserDepartment>
      <UserId>A10129</UserId>
      <UserName>Jeff Thomson</UserName>
   </User>
</rsp>
```

In MSDN, I read that I need to use `IDispatchMessageInspector` to intercept the XML that goes out. But I couldn't find any code reference or example for it.

Any good ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

So I assume your WCF service method returns an instance of a `User` object in this method call, right?

Why not just define a wrapper class called `rsp` that contains the `User` instance? Then returning the `rsp` object would render in the desired style. Just a nice clean wrapper - no messy XML manipulation on the fly......

Comment: I have to remove all the namespace information as well xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" so I have to  intercept. I found no way to remove them

Comment: @Kunal: **why** do you need to remove those xmlns= attribute?? Those are there for a good reason!

Comment: hmm I asked this question to my service user who is a j2me application developer, he said he has limited api and want to create standard function for all mobile OS(android, blackberry etc). It was difficult for him to create seperate parsers?